# Spring REST Repository based on User Data

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I am coding an app where the user works into a "Business activity". So every time a new user registers himself a new Business activity is created (or the user can join an active Business activity).

In this app there are various entities, let's take one: the pizzas. Every pizza belongs to one and only one business activity and to one and only one user.

When I send a request to the backend API point I send a token and the system gets the user and the Business activity.

Now the question: how can I fetch from frontend all the pizzas that belongs to he user A and the related business activity BA sending only the Authorization token?

My Repos are coded like this

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = true)
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> { 

}

@RepositoryRestResource(exported = true)
public interface PizzaRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Pizza, Long> { 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Every pizza belongs to one and only one business activity and to one and only one user.

So does this mean there is a One to One relationship between Pizza and User? 
(Each User will only have one pizza)

If so, you can create a field `user_id`in your Pizza Table
Then in your Pizza Entity add the property

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User user;
```

and in your User Entity add the field

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="user")
private Pizza pizza;
```